# Javascript triggering vertical scroll of the DIV tag automatically when the vertical scroll bar of the page is scrolled down

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page, and I have a <DIV> element in the page with a fixed width and height with a vertical scroll enabled for the <DIV>.

Now When I use a the vertical scroll bar for page (not the vertical scroll bar of the <DIV>) and scrolls down slowly , and when page scrolls down and reaches the <DIV> tag, and If I continue scrolling , then the scroll should take place inside the <DIV> till it reaches the bottom of the <DIV> and then after that proceed with the page scrolling.

I need to sample code with which I can achieve this behavior.

Comment: Please post some code of your attempts at achieving this. Also consider clarifying your explanation as it is quite hard to understand.

Comment: did you forget some words?